# glXGetProcAddress returns non-null for any procName starting with "gl"

Tags: opengl, opengl-extensions

I was very surprised when I discovered that the following code, and a lot of its variations, produce a non-null memory address. The variations that I tried include:

- Calling `glXGetProcAddressARB` instead of `glXGetProcAddress`.
- Having an active GL context, created with GLFW.
- Using the cross-platform alternative provided with GLFW: `glfwGetProcAddress`.

  ```
  #include <GL/glx.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      void *ptr;

      ptr = glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte *)"glottis");

      printf("ptr: %x\n", ptr);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

The programs is compiled with `-lGL` (and `-lglfw` when required) and there are no warnings nor errors.

The only way to obtain a `0` output, the `NULL` pointer, is by asking the address of a function whose name does not start with `gl`, for instance `manny`.

I am quite surprised by this behaviour because `glottis` and `manny` should be equally non-existing, and I would have expected both to produce a `NULL` pointer.

## Resources

This is an excerpt from `glXGetProcAddress` documentation.

> Notes
>
> A NULL pointer is returned if function requested is not suported in
>   the implementation being queried.
>
> GLU functions are not queryable due to the fact that the library may
>   not be loaded at the time of the query.

[Full document](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetProcAddress.xml)

[More info on this topic](http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/glXGetProcAddressNeverReturnsNULL/)

Comment: Well, from a correctness point of view, the behaviour you observe is compliant. You cannot conclude that a non-null return value of `glXGetProcAddress` (or the others) implies that the function is there or can be used. You must walways query the extension string. Trying to get function pointers for function not advertised by the extension (or implied by the core GL version) will conceptually be undefined behavior. However, I do find the observed behavior still a bit weird for a real-world implementation. Which implementation are you trying this with? I get 0 on nvidia and mesa (llvmpipe).

Comment: @derhass: You should make this an answer.

Comment: @derhass: Thank you. I feared that this was the case. I am using Mesa on Arch Linux (mesa 11.0.3-1, mesa-libgl 11.0.3-1). Upgrading to mesa 11.1.1-1 does not seem to fix the problem. The fact is, in my production code I was using `glfwExtensionSupported` to check for extension support; however, a typo made me notice this behavior and I decided to summon StackOverflow's GL experts. Please make the comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, from a correctness point of view, the behaviour you observe is compliant. You cannot conclude that a non-`NULL` return value of `glXGetProcAddress` (or the others) implies that the function is there or can be used. You must always query the extension string. Trying to get function pointers for function not advertised by the extension string (or its presence implied by the core GL version of your context) will conceptually be undefined behavior.

You did quote from the [reference page on `glXGetProcAddress`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetProcAddress.xml). Unfortunately, those reference pages are notorioulsy imprecise, incomplete, and sometimes even flat-out *wrong*. In this case, the wording is at least unfortunate.

I generally recommend using the official specifications for looking up such details. In this case, the [GLX 1.4 specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glx1.4.pdf) will be the relevant document. Section 3.3.12 "Obtaining Extension Function Pointers" states this about `glXGetProcAddress` (emphasis mine):

> A return value of `NULL` indicates that the specified function does not exist for the implementation.
>
> **A non-`NULL` return value for `glXGetProcAddress` does not guarantee that an extension function is actually supported at runtime. The client must also query
>   `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` or `glXQueryExtensionsString` to determine if an
>   extension is supported by a particular context.**
>   [...]
>
> `glXGetProcAddress` may be queried for all of the following functions:
>
> - All GL and GLX extension functions supported by the implementation (**whether those extensions are supported by the current context or not**).
> - All core (non-extension) functions in GL and GLX from version 1.0 up to and including the versions of those specifications supported by the implementation,
>     as determined by `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and `glXQueryVersion` queries.

It looks like the Mesa3D implementation is actually capable of generating some stubs dynamically for every queried function starting with `gl`.

Looking at the current version of [`/src/mapi/glapi/glapi_getproc.c`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/mapi/glapi/glapi_getproc.c?id=9fbbd60c1da4467683d93540c64164ad337ce454#n506) reveals the function `_glapi_get_proc_address()` doing this:

```
/**
 * Return pointer to the named function.  If the function name isn't found
 * in the name of static functions, try generating a new API entrypoint on
 * the fly with assembly language.
 */
_glapi_proc
_glapi_get_proc_address(const char *funcName)
{
   _glapi_proc func;
   struct _glapi_function * entry;

   init_glapi_relocs_once();

#ifdef MANGLE
   /* skip the prefix on the name */
   if (funcName[1] != 'g' || funcName[2] != 'l')
      return NULL;
#else
   if (funcName[0] != 'g' || funcName[1] != 'l')
      return NULL;
#endif

   /* search extension functions first */
   func = get_extension_proc_address(funcName);
   if (func)
      return func;

   /* search static functions */
   func = get_static_proc_address(funcName);
   if (func)
      return func;

   /* generate entrypoint, dispatch offset must be filled in by the driver */
   entry = add_function_name(funcName);
   if (entry == NULL)
      return NULL;

   return entry->dispatch_stub;
}
```

So it actually checks for the `gl` prefix, and if the function is then not known, it dynamically creates a stub for it. Later, when a hw backend driver is loaded, it might register the gl functions, and the stub code will forward the call to the driver, if it provides an implementation for it.